# Latin Extended A fonts not showing in Ckeditor

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, ckeditor4.x

I have extended ckeditor's config.js to show some special characters form Latin Extended-A set.  This shows okay in the  special characters popup. When I test my website on my development machine it works alright when I test it on my production and live website nothing shows it defaults to ordinary  character.  This is being hosted on azurewebsites. My web application is ASP.NET MVC5 and my database is MySQL.

```
config.specialChars = config.specialChars.concat(['&#256;'],
      ['&#257;'],
      ['&#362;'],
      ['&#363;'],
      ['&#332;'],
      ['&#333;'],
      ['&#298;'],
      ['&#299;'],
      ['&#274;'],
      ['&#275;']

      );
```

Has anyone had this problem and had a fix around or can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did further research and investigation and found out that if I placed the latin character in the database directly it saved. I also found out that common latin characters in ckeditor saved and committed alright to database. So I considered the problem to be between saving and the connection to database - and after research I found out that adding  charset=utf8 to the MySql connection solved the problem.